# get access top variables and methods in a different class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, artificial-intelligence

Below are the header and cpp files i am using

header

```
#include "2d/Vector2D.h"
#include <list>
#include "../../AbstTargetingSystem.h"


class AbstRaven_Bot;




class Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy
{

public:
    Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy()
    {}
    Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy(AbstRaven_Bot* owner);

    //each time this method is called the opponents in the owner's sensory 
    //memory are examined and the closest  is assigned to m_pCurrentTarget.
    //if there are no opponents that have had their memory records updated
    //within the memory span of the owner then the current target is set
    //to null

    void       pickTarget();
};
class Fletcher_TargetingSystem : public AbstTargetingSystem
{

public:
    Fletcher_TargetingSystem(AbstRaven_Bot* owner);

    //each time this method is called the opponents in the owner's sensory 
    //memory are examined and the closest  is assigned to m_pCurrentTarget.
    //if there are no opponents that have had their memory records updated
    //within the memory span of the owner then the current target is set
    //to null
    void       Update();
    void         closestBotStrategy();

    void      setCurrentTarget(AbstRaven_Bot* t);
    AbstRaven_Bot* getCurrentTarget();

    void      setCurrentOwner(AbstRaven_Bot* t);
    AbstRaven_Bot* getCurrentOwner();
};

#endif
```

cpp

```
#include "Fletcher_TargetingSystem.h"
#include "../../AbstRaven_Bot.h"
#include "../../Raven_SensoryMemory.h"
#include "../../Debug/DebugConsole.h"


//-------------------------------- ctor ---------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Fletcher_TargetingSystem(AbstRaven_Bot* owner):
AbstTargetingSystem(owner){

}

//-------------------------------- ctor ---------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy(AbstRaven_Bot* owner){

}

//----------------------------- Update ----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//#define script AbstTargetingSystem::Instance()
//class AbstTargetingSystem;
//----------------------------- closestPlayer ----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget()
{

    double ClosestDistSoFar = MaxDouble;


    for (curBot; curBot != SensedBots.end(); ++curBot)
    {
        //make sure the bot is alive and that it is not the owner
        if ((*curBot)->isAlive() && (*curBot != getCurrentOwner()) )
        {
            double dist = Vec2DDistanceSq((*curBot)->Pos(), getCurrentOwner()->Pos());
            if (dist < ClosestDistSoFar)
            {
                ClosestDistSoFar = dist;
                setCurrentTarget(*curBot);// = *curBot;
            }

        }
    }

}
void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Update()
{
    // currentStrategy = targetClosestBotStrategy;
    // target = currentStrategy.pickTarget();
    std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*> SensedBots;
    SensedBots = getCurrentOwner()->GetSensoryMem()->GetListOfRecentlySensedOpponents();

    std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*>::const_iterator curBot = SensedBots.begin();
    setCurrentTarget(0);//       = 0;

    Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy* fGCBS = new Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy(this->getCurrentOwner());
    fGCBS->pickTarget();
}

AbstRaven_Bot* Fletcher_TargetingSystem::getCurrentOwner(){
    return m_pOwner;
}
AbstRaven_Bot* Fletcher_TargetingSystem::getCurrentTarget(){
    return m_pCurrentTarget;
}

void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::setCurrentTarget(AbstRaven_Bot* t){
    m_pCurrentTarget = t;
}
void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::setCurrentOwner(AbstRaven_Bot* t){
    m_pOwner = m_pOwner;
}
```

In the  `void Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget()` I am trying to get access the curBot and SensedBot methods in the update `void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Update()`.  I also want to be able to access the `void Fletcher_TargetingSystem::setCurrentOwner(AbstRaven_Bot* t)` and the others 3 similar to dat

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your method `Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget()` you can't access to `Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Update()` variables `curBot` and `SensedBot` because their are local variables.

So, if you really need access to them, convert them to `Fletcher_TargetingSystem` class attributes, create both setters and getters and, trying to avoid `friend` clases, re-defininig your class dependencies: pass a `Fletcher_TargetingSystem` const reference to your `Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy` methods:

For example:

```
class Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy
{
    void pickTarget(const Fletcher_TargetingSystem & targeting);
    ....
};

....

class Fletcher_TargetingSystem 
{
    protected:
        std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*> SensedBots;
    public:
        std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*> & getSensedBots() const { return SensedBots; }
};

void Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget(const Fletcher_TargetingSystem & targeting)
{
    double ClosestDistSoFar = MaxDouble;
    std::list<AbstRaven_Bot*> & myLocalSensedBots = targeting.getSensedBots();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Of course this give errors, it is an explanation, not real code. If you need access to `Fletcher_TargetingSystem` public methods, pass a valid reference to a `Fletcher_TargetingSystem` object to `Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget()` as I told you. But, as I wrote, you will never have access to `curBot` and `SensedBots` outside `Fletcher_TargetingSystem::Update()` because are local variables. I hope this help.

Comment: Edit your question with new code, I think you forgot class name: must be `void Fletcher_getClosestBotStrategy::pickTarget(Fletcher_TargetingSystem & targeting)`

Comment: From where you need access?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28034/discussion-between-tio-pepe-and-alan-fletcher)